# Laravel : Unique count instead of total

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following in my controller :

```
public function countries($id)
{
    
    $country_visit = DB::table('profile_visits')
    ->where('profile_id','=', $id)
    ->select('country', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
    ->groupBy('ip')
    ->get();

  //  $new =  $country_visit->count();
 
    return compact('data','country_visit');
}
```

The output :

```
{        
    "country_visit": [
        {
            "country": "Netherlands",
            "total": 1
        },
        {
            "country": "Morocco",
            "total": 10
        },
        {
            "country": "Netherlands",
            "total": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

When I do `$new =  $country_visit->count();` it returns a count of `3` **which is true**, but I want to return a count of each country. Meaning `Morocco : 1` and `Netherlands : 2`. How to do so ?

I tried to group by 'name' but it didn't work.

Edit : Table content

[image]

Comment: can you update with your table content

Comment: @HijenHEK I did not understand what you meant ? If I have acces to the table ? Yes.

Comment: i mean update the answer with your table content

Comment: did you try and group by country

Comment: @HijenHEK Yes, it gives me this   `{"country": "Morocco","total": 10},{"country": Netherlands","total": 2}`

Comment: and what is the prefered output ?

Comment: @HijenHEK `Morocco:1` & `Netherlands:2`

Comment: but marroco is 10 ? so you want by ip ?

Comment: Morocco is 10, but there is only one Morocco. So Morocco = 1 is what I want.

Comment: the repeated morroco you want to exclude has same ip ? check my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`groupBy`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-groupby) collection helper then the [`map`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-map) collection helper to get the country count:

```
$country_visit->groupBy('country')->map(function ($item, $key) {
    return $item->count();
});
```

Alternatively you can provide multiple arguments to the [`groupBy`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#groupby-having) query.

**Update**

You are actually wanting a count of distinct ip addresses grouped by country, so:

```
$country_visit = DB::table('profile_visits')
    ->where('profile_id','=', $id)
    ->select('country', DB::raw('count(distinct ip) as total'))
    ->groupBy('country')
    ->get();
```

Comment: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::map()` is the error I'm getting. I tried adding your code to my `$country_visit`

Comment: @AlyaKra My example works on your return `$country_visit` variable, it's not part of your eloquent query.

Comment: Ok. So how can I add it directly ?

Comment: That depends. Do you want to group by `ip` or `country`, or by both?

Comment: Only country, So I will have the number by country.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But this is not what I was looking for. The output is outputting `Morocco:10` and `Netherlands:2` as you can see in the table I posted. I would want `Morocco:1` and `Netherlands:2` . This is why I grouped them by ip.

Comment: Yes! Grouped by country only. So the number of the countries named Morocco is 1, number of countries named Netherlands is 2.

Comment: Your screenshot shows `10` records for the country `Morocco`, not `1`. Where is `1` coming from?

Comment: It's the count of Morocco. Morocco has 10 records, but it's present one time. So i want the count of the times Morocco is present, which is one.

Comment: By that same logic, `Netherlands` should be `1` and not `2` which you seem to think it is.

Comment: I get what you are saying. I'm grouping them by ip, so all Morocco entries have the same ip, so Morocco =1. However Netherlands have 2 different ips, so Netherlands = 2. My bad, I failed at explaining.

Comment: @AlyaKra Then count the `distint ip` addresses in your `DB::raw`. Updated above.

Comment: Exactly. I didn't know about distinct. This is what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You basically want to group by country but without repeating those with the same ip then you use distinct on count of ip .

```
public function countries($id)
{
    $country_visit = DB::table('profile_visits')
    ->where('profile_id','=', $id)
    ->select('country', DB::raw('count(DISTINCT ip) as total'))
    ->groupBy('country')
    ->get();

    return compact('data','country_visit');
}
```

#### SQL équivalent

```
SELECT `country` , COUNT( DISTINCT `ip`) FROM `profile_visits` where profile_id = 5 GROUP BY  `country`
```

#### Example

[image: sample table]
[image: query result]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The output of your code is `{"country": "Morocco","total": 10},{"country": Netherlands","total": 2}`. I would want the count of Morocco and Netherlands. How many time is there Morocco ? 1. And how many time is there Netherlands ? 2.  So the wanted output is `Morocco : 1` and `Netherlands :2` Just the count of how many time each one is present.

Comment: Same as @ Unflux , yours is correct too. I was missing Distinct to retrive data by ip. Thank you.

Comment: i was testing it , updated it earlier , you are very welcome

Answer (score 0):

Use pluck method. check it [here,](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck)

you just need to add:

```php
...->pluck('total','country');
```

**update**

```php
    $country_visit = DB::table('profile_visits')
        ->where('profile_id', $id)
        ->select('country', DB::raw('count(DISTINCT ip) as total'))
        ->groupBy('country')
        ->pluck('total', 'country');
```

Comment: `If duplicate keys exist, the last matching element will be inserted into the plucked`
 . i think it wont count the duplicate .

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong. You need visit for each profile id per country. Is it right? if yes, so you must already have grouped query by country, so no duplicate happens here and pluck does the job, no need to use map.

Comment: but what is the job ?

Comment: @HijenHEK to get an array with countries as keys and counts as values.check update

Comment: i still think no need to use pluck , you already using the same request so you are getting countries with counts

Comment: @HijenHEK you are right. All data is included in your answer. But it was questioned how to reformat it. It's asked: "but I want to return a count of each country. Meaning Morocco : 1 and Netherlands : 2"

Comment: aa i get you now , i dont know the output exact of your code , but he mentioned already the stucture he has , and i worked upon that